# Shared variables and DLL usage questions in Visual Basic.  Scope confusion

Tags: vb.net, dll, scope, shared

I'm trying to split some prior crafted code into a DLL. It's a simple logger system.

There are a few things that need to be shared with the main form in the project, so I set them up as a shared variable, but I don't use shared stuff often, and I worry it will cause variable conflicts regarding scope. I figured I would make a post here about it and see if someone can explain what I don't fully understand.

Since this is a logger it will be used a couple of places. Other DLLs that need logging may reference it through a instanced object and project reference. My main form will also have an instanced object and a reference to the logger libary.

Since one of my properties is a connection string and it's shared, does this mean that a instance of my logger class inside a DLL will have the same shared values as a instance on my main UI form? Or will the fact that the instance is inside of a DLL provide the scope boundary I need? I'm hoping it does..

I mainly worry that I might want to log using two different connection strings down the road.

(I hope my question makes sense. If it doesn't, post comments and I'll try to clarify.)

Comment: could you show code representing how the connectionstring is being 'shared' and how your dll is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the fact that the instance is in a DLL does not provide the scope boundary you need. If the class or members in the DLL were declared `static` they would be shared and you could run into problems. So, just don't declare them `static` and be sure to create `new` instances of the object(s) when you consume them and you should be ok.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up for me. I'm probably "sharing" more than I need to but i'm also trying to stop using modules as a junk drawer so it's good to know i'm not about to shoot myself in the foot with these changes.